# What does gcc -E mean?

Tags: c, gcc, file-descriptor

I came across this option of -E while navigating and searching for where the file descriptors of stdio.h is stored in the machine? But I am not sure what exactly this command gcc -E do? Can it be used to view the file descriptor of the stdio.h fie stored in /usr/include/ directory?

Comment: Man pages are your friend. E.g. "man gcc" at the unix (or unix-based system) prompt will tell you about all the command flag options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It tells GCC to stop after the preprocessing stage. Details in the link.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options

Answer (score 5):

It will show the output the compiler produces after expanding all macros.