# What does gcc -E option stand for?

Tags: gcc, command-line-arguments, naming, cc, mnemonics

According to gcc manual, the -E option only preprocesses the .c source file, without running the compiler and just giving an input file (.i). But what does the -E stand for?

Comment: I don't understand the question: as you say, the manual says that "the -E option only preprocesses the .c source file, without running the compiler and just giving an input file (.i)". So, this option stands for "run the preprocessor on the `.c` file and don't proceed with compilation". Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193798/what-does-gcc-e-mean

Comment: @ForceBru OP asks about the etymology. Normally single-letter switches are the first letters of the things they do.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ah, okay, makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

- This option was introduced on compilers much earlier than GCC, and GCC used the same naming for compatibility.
- My best guess from the historical evidence is that `-E` stands for "expand macros".
- The authors of those earlier compilers couldn't call it `-P` because there was already a `-P` option, which also ran only the preprocessor, but wrote the output to `.i` files instead of to standard output.  `-p` was also taken.
- Over time, `-E` became preferred to `-P`, and when GCC was written, it supported only `-E` and not `-P`.

---

Despite being supposedly off topic for Stack Overflow, I think a bit of history will help explain how this option got its name.

`gcc(1)` inherited its basic command line options from much earlier Unix C compilers.  Many versions can be found in [the Unix Tree archive](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl).

It looks like the first version that supported `-E` was Research Unix V7, circa 1979:  [`cc(1)` source](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/cc.c), [man page source](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man1/cc.1).  There was also a `-P` option that also just ran the preprocessor, but sent the result to a file `foo.i` instead of to standard output.  V6 had already supported `-P` but not `-E`: [`cc(1)` source](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/s1/cc.c), [man page source](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/man/man1/cc.1).

This at least answers why `-E` wasn't named `-P` instead: because `-P` was already in use.  (And `-p` was also taken, it was used to request profiling.)  The only hint I found as to why `-E` was chosen is that the corresponding flag variable in the source code is named `exflag`.  I would hazard a guess that this stands for "expand", as what `-E` does is basically to expand macros.

It appears that `-P` was eventually deprecated in favor of `-E`.  V8 still supported it, but omitted it from the man page.  V10 (circa 1989) included two versions of the compiler, `cc` which compiled traditional C, and `lcc` for ANSI C.  The man page says that `cc` supports `-P` with the preprocessor behavior, but for lcc, `-P` did something else ("write declarations for all defined globals on standard error").  They both supported `-E`.  On other fronts, 32V and BSD, at least initially, supported both, but `-P` would emit a warning that it was obsolete and `-E` should be used instead.

It looks like `gcc`, from [its earliest version](https://github.com/huangguiyang/gcc-0.9), only supported `-E` and not `-P`.  Since then, a `-P` option has been introduced, but it does something else ("inhibit generation of linemarkers").