# Clarification of C Code containing nested structs, pointers, pointer type casting and C MACROS

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am trying to understand the following code below. It belongs to stm32f407xx microcontroller & i am trying to make sense by expanding the macros.

```
#define GPIOA_BASE_ADDR      0x12345678U
#define RCC_BASE_ADDR        0x64874547U

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t MODER;
    uint32_t OTYPER;
    uint32_t OSPEEDR;
    uint32_t PUPDR;
    uint32_t IDR;
    uint32_t ODR;
    uint32_t AFR[2];
    /* & Many more registers */
}GPIO_RegDef_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t AHB1ENR;
    uint32_t AHB2ENR;
    uint32_t AHB3ENR;
    uint32_t APB1ENR;
    uint32_t APB2ENR;
    uint32_t APB3ENR;    
    /* & Many more registers */
}RCC_RegDef_t;

#define GPIO_A           (GPIO_Regdef_t *)GPIOA_BASE_ADDR
#define RCC              (RCC_Regdef_t *)RCC_BASE_ADDR

#define GPIOA_PCLK_EN()  (RCC -> AHB1ENR |= (1 << 0))

typedef struct 
{
    uint8_t GPIO_PinNumber;
    uint8_t GPIO_PinMode;
    uint8_t GPIO_PinSpeed;
    uint8_t GPIO_PuPdControl;
    uint8_t GPIO_PinOPType;
    uint8_t GPIO_PinAltFunMode;
}GPIO_PinConfig_t;

typedef struct
{
    GPIO_Regdef_t       *pGPIOx;
    GPIO_PinConfig_t    GPIO_PinConfig;
}GPIO_Handle_t;

void GPIO_PeriClkCtrl(GPIO_RegDef_t *GPIOx)
{
    if(GPIOx == GPIOA)
    {
        GPIOA_PCLK_EN();
    }
}

GPIO_Handle_t GPIO_led;
GPIO_led.pGPIOx = GPIOA;
GPIO_led.GPIO_PinConfig.PinMode = 1;
GPIO_PeriClkCtrl(GPIOA);
```

Q.1 The line

```
#define GPIOA            (GPIO_Regdef_t *)GPIOA_BASE_ADDR`
```

expands to

```
#define GPIOA            (GPIO_Regdef_t *)0x12345678U
```

meaning, the base address of Port A is taken and in memory, a structure is created named GPIO_A and the first element of `GPIO_Regdef_t` i.e. `MODER` is assigned the base address 0x12345678U. Is this true?

Q.2

```
typedef struct
{
    GPIO_Regdef_t       *pGPIOx;
    GPIO_PinConfig_t    GPIO_PinConfig;
}GPIO_Handle_t;`
```

Here, we create a nested structure, the GPIO_PinConfig is easy to understand, i can access the GPIO_PinConfig_t structure using the . operator. *pGPIOx is making me confused. pGPIOx is defined as a pointer but,

```
GPIO_led.pGPIOx = GPIOA;
```

is written. If i expand this, is this correct?

```
GPIO_led.pGPIOx = (GPIO_Regdef_t *)0x12345678U
```

i.e. in memory, we create a structure of which its first element MODER points to 0x12345678U address? Because pointers are accessed using the -> operator whereas we access pGPIOX using the . operator. This is confusing. Even if it is defined as a pointer, do we use the . operator to set its value?

Q.3

```
GPIO_PeriClkCtrl(GPIOA);
```

Expanding Macros,

```
GPIO_PeriClkCtrl(GPIO_RegDef_t *(GPIO_Regdef_t *)0x12345678U));
```

Now, we have as address that is typecast to GPIO_RegDef_t structure as pointer which is dereferenced using * and is initiated using GPIO_RegDef_t. I didn't understand this whole statement.

How exactly is GPIO created in memory?

Comment: You can use [`gcc -E`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193798/what-does-gcc-e-mean) to have `gcc` show the expansion of macros.

Comment: Q1:  `GPIO_A` is not a _structure_ and it is just a _MACRO_ (I suppose you know that whenever you see `GPIO_A` in code it will be replaced by `(GPIO_Regdef_t *)0x12345678U`).

Comment: Q2: You would use -> operator if you created `GPIO_Handle_t *GPIO_led` (Pointer to a `GPIO_Handle_t` structure).

Comment: Q3: The most important question. The way MCUs are constructed is that some addresses in memory have special purpose. So the address for *GPIO_A* already exist and you can access it to do all kinds of stuff. The structure `GPIO_Handle_t` is there to make things easier for you. It allows you to store address in memory for your peripheries (i.e. *GPIO_A*)  and properties for those peripheries struct `GPIO_PinConfig_t`

Comment: You have conflated multiple unrelated concepts. Normally you should ask one question per post on SO.  However, for a novice it is not always easy to know that they are unrelated.  That said a soon as you start numbering questions, you are going down the wrong path.

Comment: Do not use that code.  Correct and safe definitions for STM32F407 are defined in stm32f407.h and the CMSIS in general.

Comment: @Veljko : post an answer rather then a series of comments that are more or less an answer.  Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for the constructive criticism. Since the question already has enough similar answers, I will not add an answer now. But I will look to follow your recommendation in the future

Answer (score 1):

First of all you state that this is STM32F407xx code when it clearly is not because on that platform the addresses:

```
#define GPIOA_BASE_ADDR      0x12345678U
#define RCC_BASE_ADDR        0x64874547U
```

make no sense, and will only add to your confusion.

The memory map for [STM32F407xx](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f405rg.pdf) is as follows:
[image]
In particular the GPIO base address is at 0x40020000 and RCC at 0x40023800 (both in the AHB1 space - AHB = AMBA High-performance Bus).  You would not normally define these addresses in your code, but would include the vendor supplied header for the part.  In this case stm32f407.h, which includes (elided):

```c
/*!< AHB1 peripherals */
#define GPIOA_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0000)
#define GPIOB_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0400)
.
.
.
#define RCC_BASE              (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x3800)
```

Now given all that, starting with your last question - unnumbered but presumably Q4?

> How exactly is GPIO created in memory?

It is not "created" and it is not in RAM, it is rather *memory mapped I/O*.  That is it is not memory, but hardware whose registers are accessed via the memory map.  For that to work of course, you have to have the *correct* fixed physical addresses as described above. You cannot create I/O at arbitrary locations, it is where it is defined by the hardware implementation.

The rest of the code is similarly implausible.  stm32f407.h also defines the register layout for GPIO:

```c
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t MODER;    /*!< GPIO port mode register,               Address offset: 0x00      */
  __IO uint32_t OTYPER;   /*!< GPIO port output type register,        Address offset: 0x04      */
  __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;  /*!< GPIO port output speed register,       Address offset: 0x08      */
  __IO uint32_t PUPDR;    /*!< GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register,  Address offset: 0x0C      */
  __IO uint32_t IDR;      /*!< GPIO port input data register,         Address offset: 0x10      */
  __IO uint32_t ODR;      /*!< GPIO port output data register,        Address offset: 0x14      */
  __IO uint16_t BSRRL;    /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset low register,  Address offset: 0x18      */
  __IO uint16_t BSRRH;    /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset high register, Address offset: 0x1A      */
  __IO uint32_t LCKR;     /*!< GPIO port configuration lock register, Address offset: 0x1C      */
  __IO uint32_t AFR[2];   /*!< GPIO alternate function registers,     Address offset: 0x20-0x24 */
} GPIO_TypeDef;
```

which you would do well to use rather than some re-implemented, incorrect and incomplete layout such as your `GPIO_PinConfig_t`.  Critically your definitions have the AFR at the wrong address offset, so no code using alternate pin functions (any peripheral other then GPIO) will work, and this code will not work reliably or at all with even moderate levels of compiler optimisation.  See note at the end on that.

Then with respect to Q1, yes, apart from the implausible address for your stated part.

Q2, yes the expansion is as stated, but your confusion over `.` and `->` operators is an entirely unrelated concept.  For the operator `->` the *`struct` pointer* is the *left-hand-side* operand. A `struct` member can be a pointer, the operator used to access it does not depend on the *member type*.

Q3.  The `*` character in C has multiple uses depending on context.  It is:

- the multiply operator (a binary operator with left and right operands),
- the dereference operator (a unary operator with only a right hand operand)
- The pointer type modifier - there the left0hand side is a data type, not a variable.

Your example, is a pointer-type modifier, not a dereference as you believe.

Another issue with your I/O code is that none of the register members are declared `volatile` any code using these definitions is likely to fail in code that has any level of compiler optimisation applied.  Note all those `__IO` type qualifiers in the "official" I/O header definition? That is defined in core_cm4.h as:

```c
#define     __IO    volatile
```

and is critical to correct behaviour for I/O access which need not behave like regular rear/write memory, so the compiler cannot assume that what was previously written is what will be read, or that what will be read will not have change without being explicitly written.

It is not clear that the `GPIO_PinConfig_t` is for in your code, it appears to duplicate much of the I/O map, but it is not mapped to the I/O and is likely redundant.  Certainly writing `GPIO_led.GPIO_PinConfig.PinMode = 1;` will have no effect on the GPIO. You would have to write to `GPIO_led.pGPIOx->MODER` to set the GPIO to output.  The code that is hardware dependent can be written simply as:

```c
#include <stm32f407.h"

void GPIO_PeriClkCtrl( char gpio )
{
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= 1 << (gpio - 'A') ;
}
```

Then to enable the clock GPIOA, you would write:

```c
GPIO_PeriClkCtrl( 'A' ) ;
```

for example, and the function will work for any port - where yours only works for GPIOA.  Or using strm32f407.h directly you could write:

```c
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN ;
```

A more flexible `GPIO_PeriClkCtrl()` implementation might look like:

```
void GPIO_PeriClkCtrl( uint32_t gpio_mask )
{
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= gpio_mask ;
}
```

so that then you could write for example:

```c
GPIO_PeriClkCtrl( RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN | RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN ) ;
```

to enable GPIOA and GPIOC simultaneously.

The point is you should not be defining your own MCU register map - it is too large, too complex, and too easy to get it wrong.  And it has already been done for you for pretty much any MCU you will ever use.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `GPIO_A` should say `GPIOA` or nothing makes sense. Overall this code is sloppily written.

Q1: `0x12345678U` is obviously just a dummy example address. But assuming that the actual hardware registers `MODER` and so on are located at that address and onward, for a given port, then the cast makes it possible to access that memory area through a struct type syntax. A few things of note:

- This is a bug: `#define GPIO_A (GPIO_Regdef_t *)GPIOA_BASE_ADDR`. The cast *must* use `volatile GPIO_Regdef_t*` since these are hardware registers. Or otherwise the code may break in strange and unexpected ways.
- Dirty casting from a raw memory location to a struct type is only possible because the compiler has at that point no clue what is stored at that memory location. The memory could be said to have "no effective type". In case the compiler *would* assume that some particular object of a certain type is located at that address, then we can't do casts like these.

Q2: This is just an application-tier struct - it does not access registers directly, but points at another struct which does that. The pointer is necessary because that struct is already allocated at the absolute address of the hardware registers. The registers are already in place, memory-mapped by ST upon creating the hardware. If not for the pointer, we'd get some dummy struct allocated on the stack instead, which wouldn't work.

The dot in `GPIO_led.pGPIOx` is used to access the struct object's member. The arrow operator is only necessary when you want to access what the pointer points at, for example `GPIO_led.pGPIOx->MODER`.

- Again, `GPIO_Regdef_t *pGPIOx` is a bug, must be `volatile`.

Q3: Expanding macros _correctly, `GPIO_PeriClkCtrl(GPIOA);` turns into `GPIO_PeriClkCtrl((GPIO_Regdef_t *)GPIOA_BASE_ADDR);`. No de-referencing anywhere, neither in the call nor inside that function.

---

Overall, the bogus addresses, the sloppy identifier typos, the missing `volatile` bugs etc means that this code is just some quick & dirty example that someone hacked down without trying it. So you shouldn't be using it in real programs.

Comment: Q.1 I wrote the address as a dummy, it's proper value is 0x40024000 I think.  As for the volatile, you are right about it. I'm actually learning how to program microcontrollers so, this is not a proper program. But thanks for reminding to use volatile. For Q.2 I didn't know that we could access an object member of struct that happens to be a pointer using . operator. This needed clarification. For Q.3 GPIOA is an address that is typecasted to RegDef struct, and the PeriClkCtrl has to take a pointer typecasted to the same struct in order to access the same memory location in stack?

Comment: @zzz if you are going to use 'dummy' values then you cannot claim it is for STM32F407.  The address is very specific to the part, not some arbitrary memory address.

Comment: @zzz "cast" not "casted" - past tense of "cast" is "cast" - English, like most natural languages, has quirks.